# file_get_contents() and stream_get_contents() fail to open stream

Tags: php, curl, urlencode

I'm trying to force a file to be downloaded by sending it special headers. In doing so, I have to redirect URL requests for PDF documents through my download script.

I pass a query called $seg3, which is base64_encode()ed before sending, and then base64_decode()ed and urlencoded() when trying to request the file.

I've taken a look at using,

```
if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen') == '1')
{
   $data = file_get_contents(urlencode(base64_decode($seg3)));
}
else
{
   $fp = fopen(urlencode(base64_decode($seg3)), 'rb');
   $data = stream_get_contents($fp);
   fclose($fp);
}
```

But both `file_get_contents()` and `stream_get_content()` fail with:

```
fopen($URL): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Yet when I dump the URL that is being sent, I can copy and paste it in my browser and open the file.

It only seems to occur when spaces are in the file, yet the error occurs whether I use `urlencode()` or not.

Comment: The `allow_url_fopen` check looks redundant. `fopen` and `file_get_contents` both rely on it. If it's disabled `fopen` would fail as well.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that an url returns a 404 error, but still returns regular contents as well. So while the browser may display a regular page, this function will fail because of the result code.

Comment: The URL is fine though. If I enter it in the browser manually, it downloads the file. Through stream_get_contents() or file_get_contents(), they both fail _only_ when a PDF document has a space in its name.

Comment: @BrettAlton: Having a space in it's name means that this is not a valid URI. Spaces in URIs need to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been fixed already, but if there are spaces urlencode($url) might solve your problem.

Comment: I don't believed I fixed that issue yet. PS I stated in the question "It only seems to occur when spaces are in the file, yet the error occurs whether I use urlencode() or not."

Comment: Any chance you could switch to CURL? You'd have a lot more control over the headers and I noticed a large decrease in the number of errors after switching over our code to it.